# Create clone table without index

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a cloned table(tableA_cloned) from original table(tableA). But don't want to create index/key other than PK and unique key.
**I have a list of tables, so manually writing/editing create stmt is not easy.**

eg.
**tableA** create stmt

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `entry_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `job_id` (`job_id`)
);
```

**tableA_cloned** **`desired`**  create stmt

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs_cloned` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `entry_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

mysql table descriptions image:
[image]

I have already tried `create table tableA_cloned like tableA;` which creates all the indexes from original table and `create table tableA_cloned select * from tableA where 1=2;` which drops every key including PK.

Comment: `select top 0 * into new_table from current_table`

Comment: @stu there is no top in mysql , mysql equivalent is limit at the end of statement

Comment: Make a copy by `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` (or by `CREATE TABLE .. LIKE` if you mean "cloned" as "structure only") then remove non-unique keys (INFORMATION_SCHEMA, stored procedure, dynamic SQL).

Comment: Oops lol, sitting at sqlserver currently! `select * ... limit 0` ;)

Comment: @Akina then to remove non-unique keys I have to manually delete them one-by-one? please provide example/reference if possible.

Comment: No, you may use stored procedure and rempve all non-unique keys from all tables in iterative cycle. Search - there are questions about "get list of indices".